# Duda con respecto al uso de SUPER en java

Tags: java, herencia, interface, override

Tengo principalmente dudas en 2 casos

1.Aca mi pregunta es con lo siguiente SuperInterfaz.super.defaultMethod() se que esta linea hace referencia al metodo default de la interfaz pero lo que no comprendo es lo del super porque funciona el codigo asi ? donde surge la herencia o clase padre de la interfaz?

```
interface SuperInterfaz{
    default void defaultMethod(){
        System.out.println(" Metodo default desde SuperInterfaz");
    };
}
public class TestClass implements SuperInterfaz{
    

    @Override
    public void defaultMethod() {
        SuperInterfaz.super.defaultMethod(); 
    }
     
    
    @Override
    public void mensajeSuperInterfaz() {
        System.out.println("Desde TestClass !");
    }
    
     public static void main(String[] args) {
        TestClass test=new TestClass();

        test.defaultMethod();
        
    }
}
```

2.La otra duda es algo similar pero es con el cuerpo del constructor , aca lo que hace es sobrescribir un metodo pero solo para esa intancia eso es lo que entiendo pero en "super.mensajeSuperInterfaz()" el super nose porque hace referencia a TestClass y puede invocar el metodo.

```
public class TestClass implements SuperInterfaz{

    @Override
    public void defaultMethod() {
        SuperInterfaz.super.defaultMethod();
    }
     
    
    public void mensajeSuperInterfaz() {
        System.out.println("Desde TestClass !");
    }
    
     public static void main(String[] args) {
        TestClass test=new TestClass(){
            @Override
            public void mensajeSuperInterfaz() {
                super.mensajeSuperInterfaz(); 
            }    
        };
        test.mensajeSuperInterfaz();
        test.defaultMethod();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

En el primer caso tu clase `TestClass` implementa la interfaz SuperInterfaz. La palabra reservada `super` se puede usar para hacer referencia a:

- la clase padre.
- las interfaces que se implementen.

Originalmente (antes de la versión 8 de Java) no había métodos `default` en Java y `super` sólo podía usarse para hacer referencia a la clase heredada, pero la versión 8 añadió esta nueva funcionalidad y, para evitar ambigüedades, es necesario poner el nombre de la interfaz delante de `super` para acceder a los métodos `default` que queremos llamar.

Si eliminas el nombre de la interfaz, da un error de compilación:

> ```
> error: cannot find symbol
>     super.defaultMethod();
> ```

Y el IDE da más detalles:

> ```
> The method defaultMethod() is undefined for the type Object
> ```

Esto siginifica que está buscando el método en las clases padres (en este caso sólo tenemos Object, que es la clase padre de todas las demaś clases).

---

En el segundo caso se te escapa un detalle: lo que se está creando ahí es una **clase anónima** que ***extiende*** `TestClass`. La variable es de tipo `TestClass` porque siempre puedes asignar una instancia de una clase a una variable que declare como tipo una clase padre de la misma. Ese código sería funcionalmente equivalente a:

```
public class TestClass implements SuperInterfaz {

  @Override
  public void defaultMethod() {
    SuperInterfaz.super.defaultMethod();
  }

  public void mensajeSuperInterfaz() {
    System.out.println("Desde TestClass !");
  }

  private static class ChildTestClass extends TestClass {
    @Override
    public void mensajeSuperInterfaz() {
      super.mensajeSuperInterfaz();
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    TestClass test = new ChildTestClass(); //ahora no es anónima
    test.mensajeSuperInterfaz();
    test.defaultMethod();
  }
}
```